# Group data by one column and select first occurences from two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I need to `.groupby()` using `customer`, and then add a column for the date in which the customer made his/her first purchase, and add another column for the corresponding purchase amount.

Here is my code. I am doing the first part wrong and don't know how to do the second. I've tried `.loc` and `.idxmin` ....

```
mydata = [{'amount': 3200, 'close_date':'2013-03-31', 'customer': 'Customer 1',},
          {'amount': 1430, 'close_date':'2013-11-30', 'customer': 'Customer 1',},
          {'amount': 4320, 'close_date':'2014-03-31', 'customer': 'Customer 2',},
          {'amount': 2340, 'close_date':'2015-05-18', 'customer': 'Customer 2',},
          {'amount': 4320, 'close_date':'2015-06-29', 'customer': 'Customer 2',},]

df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
df.close_date = pd.to_datetime(df.close_date)
df['first_date'] = df.groupby('customer')['close_date'].min().apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))
```

Comment: The result of your groupby statement is another dataframe with two columns - "customer" and the first date. You can't assign that to a column of the original dataframe. Are you trying to create a new dataframe with information about each customer and their first purchase and the amount of that purchase? Or are you trying to add that information to the original dataframe?

Comment: Sorry, it's actually a Series object, not a dataframe.

Comment: LaterCoder, I'm trying to add a couple of columns to the original dataframe but I'm ok to make a separate DF.  Basically, I'm trying to find the first date of purchase and the purchase amount on that date.  All I need is a dataframe with that info regardless of if it is the original or not.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you sort your data by `close_date`, you can do as follows:

```
df.sort_values('close_date').groupby(['customer'])['close_date', 'amount'].first()

           close_date  amount
customer                     
Customer 1 2013-03-31    3200
Customer 2 2014-03-31    4320
```

`.sort_values()` has been added in `0.17`, used to be `sort()` [(see docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

Comment: Might want to note that this needs the data to be sorted.

Comment: I get this error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort_values'`

Comment: You're using an older version of pandas then. It'd be `.sort` for you (or upgrade if you can).

Answer (score 0):

Two steps.

First the day of first purchase:

```
In [34]: first = df.groupby('customer').close_date.min()

In [35]: first
Out[35]:
customer
Customer 1    2013-03-31
Customer 2    2014-03-31
Name: close_date, dtype: object
```

We'll use first as an indexer,

```
In [36]: idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(first.iteritems()), names=['customer', 'close_date'])

In [37]: idx
Out[37]:
MultiIndex(levels=[['Customer 1', 'Customer 2'], ['2013-03-31', '2014-03-31']],
           labels=[[0, 1], [0, 1]])
```

For a DataFrame with those two levels

```
In [38]: df2 = df.set_index(['customer', 'close_date'])

In [39]: df2.loc[idx]
Out[39]:                       
                         amount
customer   close_date
Customer 1 2013-03-31    3200
Customer 2 2014-03-31    4320
```

This is a series, you can use `.unstack()` to get back a DataFrame.